# How to retrieve dynamic attribute based on other document attributes?

Tags: mongodb

My document looks like this:

```
{ 
  draft: "<draft_content>",
  published: "<published_content>"
}
```

When I update document, I update only `"draft"` OR both `"draft"` and `"published"`. So document may look like this:

```
{
  draft: "B",
  published: "A"
}

or

{
  draft: "B",
  published: "B"
}
```

What I need, is to retrieve all documents with information if `draft === published`, without actually returning `draft` and `published` fields. In SQL I would do this like this:

```
select (draft = published)::boolean as is_published from documents;
```

Is it possible to do that in MongoDB?

I thought also about storing `isPublished: true/false` flag in each document, but when I am updating `draft` it is not possible to determine if `draft` is different from `published` or not. For example if I had document `{draft: "A", published: "A", isPublished: true}` then updating it with `{draft: "A", isPublished: false}` would change status of isPublished even though draft was the same as published...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has no dedicated support for this. You can however use `$where` to achieve this.

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.draft == this.published" }, {id:1} )
```

This will give you only the ids of the document where `draft` equals `published`. But mongo will do a full table scan I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that if I want to avoid retrieving "draft" and "published" I will have to compute and store hash of each of them to compare on client side.